# Pass Json into azure Data factory->store procedure as parameter to insert data. It shows success but not inserted data into table

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure which will receive a JSON from Azure Data Factory -> stored procedure and I want to insert JSON data into a table.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDataLake
    (@reports nvarchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataLake2] (location_id, h0)
        SELECT j2.location_id, j2.h0
        FROM OPENJSON (@reports, '$.reports') j
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value]) 
                    WITH (location_id int,
                          h0 int) j2 
        WHERE j.[key] = 'value'
END
```

Below is the JSON of Azure Data Factory -> stored procedure:

```
{
    "name": "Stored procedure1",
    "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[InsertDataLake]",
        "storedProcedureParameters": {
            "reports": {
                "value": {
                    "value": "@string(activity('Lookup2').output.value[0].data.reports[item()])",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabaseYeasin",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    }
}
```

This is the input of the stored procedure:

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[InsertDataLake]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "reports": {
            "value": "{\"location_id\":1580,\"date\":\"2023-05-24\",\"h0\":0,\"h1\":0,\"h2\":0,\"h3\":0,\"h4\":0,\"h5\":0,\"h6\":0,\"h7\":0,\"h8\":0,\"h9\":0,\"h10\":3,\"h11\":0,\"h12\":0,\"h13\":0,\"h14\":3,\"h15\":0,\"h16\":0,\"h17\":0,\"h18\":0,\"h19\":0,\"h20\":0,\"h21\":0,\"h22\":0,\"h23\":0,\"peak_hour\":10,\"total\":6,\"location_name\":\"Z1-B5(CR)-L5-M\"}",
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your input `reports` Json, there is no array to do cross apply. Thus, you can remove the line `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value])` from the stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE      PROCEDURE InsertDataLake(@reports nvarchar(max))
AS BEGIN

    insert into [dbo].[DataLake2] (location_id,h0)
    select j2.location_id, j2.h0
    FROM OPENJSON (@reports, '$.reports') j
    --CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value]) 
     WITH (
            location_id int,
            h0 int
     ) j2 --where j.[key] = 'value'
END
```

[image]

If you execute this stored procedure using pipeline, data will be inserted to the table.